# HyperJAXB: How to use always @OneToOne instead of @ManyToOne

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb, xsd, hyperjaxb

HyperJAXB generates @ManyToOne Annotations for XSD 1:1-relationships like:

```
<xs:element name="typeName" type="otherType" />
```

or

```
<xs:element name="typeName" type="otherType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
```

This is not the expected behaviour since it should generate @OneToOne Annotations. Well, the customization guide describes that you can customize this behaviour by adding instructions to every single element definition (see http://confluence.highsource.org/display/HJ3/Making+schema-derived+classes+ready+for+JPA, paragraph "Mapping as one-to-one").

This is fine, but I need a global configuration for this. Can anybody please tell me, what to put in bindings.xjb to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch X:1 by default to one-to-one globaly:

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <hj:persistence>
        <hj:default-to-one>
            <hj:one-to-one/>
        </hj:default-to-one>
    </hj:persistence>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

However be warned, I think I've opted to `@ManyToOne` by default for a reason. It was safer and easier to handle.

Comment: Hi, what is the schema for hj namespace? I am asking because I would like to add these binding settings directly into XSD schema itself.

Comment: @kensai https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/tree/master/ejb/schemas/customizations/src/main/resources

Comment: thx a lot! either I understand the project is not in active dev, it is really superior for those who model in XSD first, as me for middleware...